# Jsoup table query

Tags: jsoup

I'm an infrequent programmer and am trying to learn Java. I've got a web project I'd like to do and came across Jsoup which seems excellent - except I can't get what I want from the webpage (I'm sure the answer is very simple). Can someone (with as much detail as possible) explain how I extract 280.00 from the row of this table? The 10 could be used to identify the unique row (as there are a few other rows in the table).

I've ended up with this code:-

```
// Take the 3rd column of the table called tabletext and extract the 3rd element only

Elements entry =document.select(".tabletextd:eq(3)").eq(2);
System.out.println(entry.text());
```

Is that reasonable or is there a better way?

Thanks,

Mark

```
 <tr align="center" style="background:#FFFFFF">
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10.00</td>
    <td>&pound;0.00</td>
    <td>&pound;280.00</td>
      <td>
      <a href="/cart.php?action=add&qty=10&id=2628" title="Click here to add this item to your cart">
      <img alt="Click here to add this item to your cart" src="/images/addtocart.gif" border="0" />
      </a>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table has an id of tabletext, this is how I coded it up:

```
    String html =
            "<table id='tabletext'>" +
            "<tr align='center' style='background:#FFFFFF'>" +
            "<td>10</td>" +
            "<td>10.00</td>" +
            "<td>&pound;0.00</td>" +
            "<td>&pound;280.00</td>" +
            "<td>" +
            "<a href='/cart.php?action=add&qty=10&id=2628' title='Click here to add this item to your cart'>" +
            "<img alt='Click here to add this item to your cart' src='/images/addtocart.gif' border='0' />" +
            "</a>" +
            "</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "</table>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);

    Elements elements = doc.select("#tabletext > tbody > tr > td");
    Element e = elements.get(3); //this is the 4th column
    System.out.println(e.text());
```

If it has a class of tabletext, then use `.tabletext` in the `doc.select`.  You said the table had a name of `tabletext`, so that led me to believe it was an id versus a class.